# turn each element in list to key value pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists

```
list1 = [1,a,2,b,3,c]
list2 = [5,d,6,e,7,f]
```

I tried to use `list(zip(list1, list2))`

Then is what I got:

```
[(1, 5), ('a', 'd'), (2, 6), ('b', 'e'), (3, 7), ('c', 'f')]
```

I want something like this to be my output:

```
{1:a, 5:d, 2:b, 6:e, 3:c,7:f}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Via `iter` and `zip`:

```
>>> it = iter(list1 + list2)
>>> dict(zip(it,it))
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 5: 'd', 6: 'e', 7: 'f'}
```

Comment: there is a *hacky* quality to this answer which some might not be so fond of. But i am +1!

Comment: I don't see the hack, it is similar to the 'grouper' recipe at https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: @Ev.Kounis It's not hacky IMO, I actually saw core CPython developer Raymond Hettinger use this kind of `zip()` on an iterator https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577916-fast-minmax-function/?in=user-178123

Comment: @SaiKumar `iter()` creates an iterator (read here if you're not familar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do). The iterator is consumed via `next()` calls (unlike say a list), thus `zip()` creates the correct pairs

Comment: it returns an iterable (here called `it`) that will yield an item each time you call `next(it)`. You can try this out: `a = iter([1, 2, 3])` `next(a)` `next(a)` `next(a)` `next(a)`

Answer (score 2):

I'd first add your two lists together

```
>>> values = list1 + list2
>>> values
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 5, 'd', 6, 'e', 7, 'f']
```

Then use a `dict` comprehension to stride through the list by every other element, and zip that against the same stride but offset by one.

```
>>> {key:value for key,value in zip(values[::2], values[1::2])}
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 5: 'd', 6: 'e', 7: 'f'}
```